# Do I really need to encrypt data?

Tags: android

I want to create a simple app which will store some secret information. I will ask the user to create a password for the purpose. Will that be enough to secure information or should I make some other provisions also like encrypting data. Kindly provide suitable guidance.

Comment: Personally, as a user I would like to think any password was encrypted. People will inevitably use their google/facebook/banking password in your app (whether that's clever or not) and be up at arms if there is any reference to it directly in the app. There's also issues around the app having internet access etc with an unencrypted password.

Comment: What sort of secret information will you be storing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you are storing passwords, you should encrypt them. [Check this link](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/ListCipher.html) to get the list of all possible encryption/decryption options.

Answer (score 1):

As you are telling that the data is secure , you should always encrypt inspite of password protection.

Answer (score 0):

yes Mohit, while storing such secret information on mobile you need to encrypt these type of information for better security.

Have a look at this [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Don't encrypt the passwords. Instead, use Salted Hashing(SHA-2) with random salts(At least 16 bytes) for each user. Then, run the hash through another hashing algorithm, and use that hash to encrypt your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to encrypt the data using a secure encryption algorithm like AES and generate the key **in a secure way** from the user's password thus making each users data encrypted uniquely.  The passwords should be stored using a salted hash (like bcrypt or PBKDF2) so that they are not susceptible to rainbow table attacks (where hashes are precomputed in a table for matching).

One drawback of this scheme is that you can have data-loss if the user forgot their password as neither their password nor the data will be recoverable.  If the data does not need to be secured that tightly then you can generate **a secure key** and use it to encrypt all data with the same key, but the password should definitely be hashed and salted when stored back in your data-store regardless.